# How to store my contacts encrypted?

Tags: encryption, linux, keepass

I use KeePass for storing my passwords.

What should I use if I want to store my several hundred contacts (name, phone number, email, etc) encrypted?

Comment: What is your threat model (see the faq).  Do you also plan to encrypt all your email (including headers like To:, and From: for incoming mail?), and your phone log, etc?  Or do you just see some special risk for a collection of contacts all in one place?  Do you want access from multiple machines?  Cross-platform?  Read-write?

Comment: this question seems to be missing some essential information to be answerable. Please update, or close...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will just use an ODS file on a LUKS encrypted HDD.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create an encrypted virtual disk. For example truecrypt provides a way to create encrypted files that can be used as storage. (All you need is to mount the file once with the pass and you can use it like any storage place, then unmount and it's secured)

Or else you can also crypt/uncrypt an archive file with GnuPG but that will be more a burden to decrypt everytime you want to access it then recrypt it etc.

Comment: Earlier I installed my Fedora on an encrypted VG. So I need a plus thing like I mentioned with the passwords (keepass)